# Short-circuit needed when passing a parameter

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I have a CheckBoxList control in a webform which gives all 7 weekdays.
it becomes a parameter in a stored procedure in SQL Server, as part of my WHERE clause:

```
AND (@Weekdays = 'MONDAY|TUESDAY|WEDNESDAY|THURSDAY|FRIDAY|SATURDAY|SUNDAY|' 
    OR a.DAYOFWEEK in 
        (select value from dbo.convertDelimetedValueListIntoTable(@Weekdays, '|'))
    )
```

because 99% of the time all 7 weekdays remain checked, The idea is to ignore this "AND" condition and speed up the query.
So I was hoping that by using the logical operator OR, I would be able to short-circuit the second part of the condition when the first part returned true.
But I found out that SQL Server doesn't use short-circuiting.

Any ideas on how to "bypass" that line when all weekdays are selected ?

Comment: If you're building the query in code, why not exempt the condition before passing it off to SQL?

Comment: I am guessing the reason you want to bypass that function is performance? You could parse that first so it isn't done for every single row of your main query. You might also be able to make it much faster, but that requires you to post the contents of that function. I have a gut feeling it is a multistatement table valued function which are horribly slow.

Comment: Modifying the query is the best solution but if you can't, adding a t-sql constraint on this column should allow the optimizer to bypass this condition

Answer (score 0):

Could always use a CASE statement:

```
WHERE CASE
  WHEN @Weekdays='MONDAY|TUESDAY|WEDNESDAY|THURSDAY|FRIDAY|SATURDAY|SUNDAY|' THEN
    1=1
  ELSE
    a.DAYOFWEEK IN (SELECT value FROM dbo.convertDelimetedValueListIntoTable(@Weekdays, '|'))
END
```

Comment: I had tried the CASE statement with the 1=1 condition but I keep getting the following error message:    incorrect syntax near '='